# Why should the particles meet at a common point?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, time, velocity

I saw a question in my physics book asking for the time when all the three particles (each at the corner of an equilateral triangle and each having constant velocity *v* along the sides of the triangle) meet at a common point.

[image]

I can't find the reason why these particles should meet at a common point.

What I think is that since they all have the same velocity and each travels the same distance so after some time ($ t = \frac{a}{v}$) ($a$ is the side of the triangle) their corners should be interchanged and this should continue all the time and they should never be at the same point.

But it is not the answer and the solution shows that they met at the centroid of the triangle.

[image]

Why should they follow a curved path? Shouldn't they just go on along the sides of the triangle?

Comment: Probably each particle has a velocity that always points toward the next particle, not along the side - this is a common exercise.

Comment: Are you sure it said along the sides?

Comment: Why is the tag "special relativity" attached?

Comment: I think @Janvier is right. Think about it for a while. It's pretty obvious the particles will never meet if they stay on the triangle.

Comment: Was there any indication of masses in your physic problem? If such is the case a simple symmetry would help you to conclude that the 3 particles should converge toward their center of masses.

Comment: @dan the bodies were of equal masses say **m**.

Comment: You say "yes the velocity is along the sides".   With that phrase the question makes no sense.  Can you post the exact wording?  It is possible that the question is poorly phrased.

Comment: The problem should state the particles move at a constant SPEED, each toward the one ahead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's possible that you either misunderstood the problem or that it was badly phrased. I think you're right that if the particles were simply moving in straight lines with a constant velocity, they would never meet.

I believe, however, that the problem was probably intended as a [Pursuit Curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pursuit_curve)-type problem: the particles are initially at the vertices of a triangle, but each particle "pursues" the other, with their velocity directed towards the particle they're pursuing. $A$ pursues $B$, $B$ pursues $C$, and $C$ pursues $A$. (In other words, the points $A$, $B$, and $C$ represent the particles, and not fixed vertices of some triangle.)

Comment: do you mean that the particles were moving towards each other and not along the sides ?? And this was the reason behind them moving on a curved path ??

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much what everyone here is saying :)

Comment: since they are moving on a curved path shouldn't they be experiencing a force  ?? If yes can we calculate that force and also why did we use  $t =\frac{distance}{speed}$ ??

Comment: This is a kinematics problem, invoking forces is of no use. If you really wish to tho, just think there's some (perhaps pretty complex) external force that *makes sure* they move with constant velocity.

Comment: Hi @Ankit, as I can see it, this is not a physics question, but mathematics one. I think it's good to think of them as three people chasing each other like I described above. Furthermore, no one here has used time = distance/speed. What I think needs to be done is a differential equation needs to be written and then solved. It's been explained in three different answers now :)

Comment: @JohnyO42  I think it's not a kinematics problem but a general physics question and I want to know the cause of that force  and also it's direction. Also were all of them under same force ??

Comment: @Ankit Do you have a reason for thinking that?

Comment: I think absolutely that you are right (+1), but aren't they in pursuit of each other on the triangle too?

Comment: @descheleschilder Not really, no. As I understand such problems, the individuals that are doing the pursuing keep their velocities constant but change their directions as a function of the instantaneous direction between them and the pursued. So while *initially* the velocity between $A$ and $B$ would be along the triangle's arm, the minute $B$ moves, the direction of $A$'s velocity would change, and the same goes for $B$ and $C$ and so on. The wiki article makes it quite clear, I think.

Comment: Yeah, I guess you're right, due to the vertices in the triangle. If the triangle could be transformed into a line (which is impossible) they would chase each other until they drop dead.

Answer (score 2):

The question says that the particles always point towards each other. This is a very famous question in India for Jee's preparation for kinematics. Here is the question:

> Three particles A, B, and C are situated at the vertices of an equilateral triangle ABC with sides d at t = 0. Each of the particles moving with constant speed always has its velocity along AB, B along BC and C along CA. At what time will the particles meet each other?

With the associated diagram which is exactly what you have given. Here the triangle always  refers to the traingle made by the particles as its vertices.

So in this case obviously the particles cant move in a straight path.

Another challenge that my teacher had proposed to me was to find the equation trajectory of the particles. Good Luck!

Comment: @descheleschilder since A has its velocity always along AB doesn't this mean that it will move along the sides ??

Comment: This is a very badly worded question.  The triangle shouldn't be named as "ABC".  The expression "velocity along with" isn't someone one would normally say in English.

Comment: @Ankit Why do you ask this question to me? I only made it better readable. It was the OP who answered this question. But I agree that it suggests that the particles stay on the triangle.

Comment: @Ankit the triangle ABC is always the triangle formed by the particles. Understand the questions feelings. I edited the answer now

Comment: @Ray Butterworth , I am sorry about that i had used google lens to scan the question. It might have messed up.

Comment: **Each of the particles moving with constant speed always has its velocity parallel to the sides of the triangle.** This is **not** the case.

Comment: "*… google lens to scan the question …*".  I wasn't complaining about *your* posting.  I was pointing out that if that text *is* the source of the OP's question, then I can understand why it produced confusion in the first place.

Comment: The velocities do point **not** along (parallel to) the sides of the triangle...

Answer (score 1):

If the velocities are all equal and always directed towards the position of the other particles, the velocity vectors will start rotating. Each particle at an equal rate. So the velocities will converge to the point in the middle.
What will happen to the particles after they've reached that point of coincidence? You can probably imagine yourself. The particles still have the same velocity (if the collision is elastic) but opposite in direction. So they will start diverging back to the triangle after which the process repeats itself. A Perpetuum Mobile! (Which, of course, in reality, is impossible).

Answer (score 0):

Another way to see this, is by leveraging symmetry, since the whole system is invariant under a rotation of $ 120^{\circ} $ or integer multiple of that.  Suppose they **do not** meet at the center, but some nearby point P.

Now since the answer should also not depend on whether or not you rotate the whole system by certain angles, meeting at point P is obviously wrong, because the position of point P is not invariant under such rotations. We are left to conclude that they must meet at the center of the triangle.

Comment: but why should they meet or go on a curved path ??

Comment: Because each particle doesn't aim at the vertex of the original triangle, but rather at the next particle. See this math.stackexchange thread on the same problem:   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44896/the-vertices-of-an-equilateral-triangle-are-shrinking-towards-each-other

Comment: @JohnyO42 This is a very nice solution. The only problem I can see with it, however, is that it assumes that they meet. What if they never met? Wouldn't the argument fail?

Comment: @Philip The problem can essentially be phrased like such: All 3 particle moves such that they always holds an angle (in this case $ 30^{\circ} $ ) with Point O (where they will eventually meet). This is easy to see, because the triangle they form only shrinks and turns, stays similar. Then since the angle they hold is constant, they always have a velocity component towards point O, hence they meet. I asked the same question some time ago here, keep in mind I went down a totally wrong path regarding the equation for the curve :       https://bit.ly/3luXO2l

Comment: I see! Very nice.

Comment: @Philip I just want to know that which force can cause them to move in such a pattern ?

Comment: 1) We have all mentioned that such a question doesn't make sense for the problem the way we all understand it. 2) If there *was* such a force, then its only effect would be to change the (direction of the) velocity of $A$ depending on the separation between $A$ and $B$, and change the velocity of $B$ depending on the separation of $B$ and $C$, and change the velocity of $C$ depending on the separation of $C$ and $A$. I know of no such "selective" forces.

Answer (score 0):

If the speed is constant then the acceleration must be centripetal, which determines the curvature of the arcs which meet at the center of the triangle. The acceleration is determined by the speed of the particle at the apex ahead. From the point of view of particle (1), the particle (2) ahead moves through an arc: v cos($30^o$)dt/L (where L is the instantaneous length of the side of the triangle). In that same short time, the velocity vector of particle (1) rotates through that same angle:  dv/v.  Equate these to find the acceleration: dv/dt.  Note that as L gets smaller, the acceleration and curvature increase.

Comment: can you tell me what does this **v cos(30o)dt/L (where L is the instantaneous length of the side of the triangle)** represent ?

Comment: The  v cos($30^o$)dt is the perpendicular displacement of the particle ahead in a time dt. The L is the radius measured from particle (1).