# How do I find the acceleration of a particle in this particular condition?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics

[image]

Three particles are located at the vertices of an equilateral triangle of side
$a$. They all start moving simultaneously with the same constant speed $v$
with the 1st particle always heading for the 2nd, the 2nd particle always
heading for the 3rd and 3rd is always heading for the 1st. Now I was wondering how can I find out the acceleration of any particle at a given moment of time? Does anyone have any insights?

Comment: i have added a figure

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why should the particles meet at a common point?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/576424/why-should-the-particles-meet-at-a-common-point)

Answer (score 3):

At any point of time, 1 observes that 3 moves towards it with a speed $v+v\cos60^{\circ}=\frac{3}{2}\cdot v$. so the length of side of the equilateral triangle formed by the three particles as a function of time can be given as $l(t)=l(0)-\frac32vt$. 1 also observes that the velocity of 2 and 3 perpendicular to the line joining them with 1 is $v\sin 60^{\circ}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}v$. Hence the triangle rotates with angular speed $\omega=\frac{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}v}{l(0)-\frac32vt}=\frac{\sqrt{3}v}{2l(0)-3vt}$. Note that this is also the angular speed at which the tangent to the trajectory of particle 2 rotates (here the tangent to the trajectory of 2 is obviously the line joining 2 and 3). Now the acceleration of 2 is simply (because the speed doesn't change, just the direction changes)$v\cdot\omega=\frac{\sqrt{3}v^2}{2l(0)-3vt}$. The same will hold for all other particles.